# SSL certificate installation on Wildfly server

Tags: ssl, wildfly, keystore

I was trying to install SSL certificate on wildfly application server which is hosted in aws Ec2 instance.
I purchased SSL certificate in godaddy. I downloaded SSL ssl certificate zip from godaddy portal. Which consists of following 
1 .gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
2 .gdig2.crt.pem
3. 70c350d31695.crt
4. 70c350d31695.pem

Created keystore and imported certificates in to keystore with following command

keytool -genkey -alias wildfly -keyalg RSA -keystore wildfly.jks

keytool -import -alias root -keystore wildfly.jks -trustcacerts -file 70c350d31695.crt

keytool -import -alias intermed  -keystore wildfly.jks -trustcacerts -file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Also done configuration in wildfly as follows
standalone.xml

```
<security-realm`enter code here` name="SslRealm">
      <server-identities>
         <ssl>
            <keystore path="/home/centos/ssl/newssl/wildfly.jks" alias="wildfly" keystore-password="OHGv216TZDhbd" />
          </ssl>
      </server-identities>
  </security-realm>

and
  <https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SslRealm"/>
```

But after restarts application, keystore recognized but https certificates not recognized. When i am double click on certificate in browesr it has only keystore information not certificate information.
Please help me to fix this.

In browser certificate error like following 
[image]

Comment: You cannot obtain certificate(s) from a CA and then create the privatekey (and keystore). You must FIRST create the privatekey, THEN the CSR, THEN obtain the certificate(s), and import to the already-existing keystore -- and the existing privatekey entry, for the leaf cert. See the instructions at https://www.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239 and neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316340/godaddy-ssl-certificate-keystore-installation-tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single entry I think in your keystore with all the details. You might find it easier using KSE (https://keystore-explorer.org/) rather than the cli

Answer (score -1):

It's literally impossible. I set up two-way SSL on Android and WildFly and I can't get one-way SSL to work with WildFly. These SSL providers only work in high-level applications like AWS EC2 and Google App Engine. There's absolutely no tutorials on installing these certificates in WildFly.

I've been trying to set up GoDaddy and Comodo certificates on WildFly for hours.

Certbot with Let's Encrypt works perfectly on WildFly. Unfortunately, stupid iOS doesn't work with Let's Encrypt.

Your only option is to use a 3rd party proxy application like Nginx.